# WorksheetFunction.CountA Using Named Cells on Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the following functional code that references named cells on Sheet1 individually:

```
Dim emp1 As Boolean
Dim emp2 As Boolean
Dim emp3 As Boolean

With Sheet1

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("AI"), .Range("AM"), .Range("AQ")) = 0 And wVOE1 = False And IsEmpty(.Range("DQ")) Then
    emp1 = False
Else
    emp1 = True
End If
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("FH"), .Range("FL"), .Range("FP")) = 0 And wVOE2 = False And IsEmpty(.Range("IV")) Then
    emp2 = False
    Else
    emp2 = True
End If
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("KL"), .Range("KP"), .Range("KT")) = 0 And wVOE3 = False And IsEmpty(.Range("NZ")) Then
    emp3 = False
Else
    emp3 = True
End If
End With
```

Ultimately, I'd like to learn how to use the CountA function with a range rather than citing individual cells.  I originally tried the following code, which did not work:

```
Dim emp1 As Boolean
Dim emp2 As Boolean
Dim emp3 As Boolean

With Sheet1

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AI:AT")) = 0 And wVOE1 = False And IsEmpty(Sheet1.[DQ]) = True Then _
    emp1 = False _
Else _
    emp1 = True
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("FH:FS")) = 0 And wVOE2 = False And IsEmpty(Sheet1.[IV]) Then _
    emp2 = False _
Else _
    emp2 = True
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("KL:KW")) = 0 And wVOE3 = False And IsEmpty(Sheet1.[NZ]) Then _
    emp3 = False _
Else _
    emp3 = True

End With
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the latter code didn't work.  Is there a way to reference the range?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `didn't work` - how did it not work? If the ranges are on different sheets, you will need to qualify the sheet, like so: `Sheet2.Range("AI:AT")` or `Sheet3.Range("AI:AT")`. Or `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AI:AT")`

Comment: emp1, emp2, and emp3 were only dependent on variables wVOE1, wVOE2, and wVOE3.  For example, if wVOE=false and sheet1.[AI] was filled, emp1 would be returned as false. @ScottHoltzman

Comment: When I qualified as such: WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("AI:AT")) , it returns as 0, even when cells are filled. I also tried the Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AI:AT"), which also returned 0.  @ScottHoltzman

Comment: In the second code block your `With Sheet1` block isn't being used by the enclosed code.

Comment: hard do help more without seeing data

Comment: @TimWilliams Why is that? How can I edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my named cells mirrored column names, Excel interpreted my cell ranges to be column ranges, which is why my code was not working.  I added a "." before range (as was suggested previously), and a "z1" to the beginning of all of my cell names, and the code now is functional:

```
Dim emp1 As Boolean
Dim emp2 As Boolean
Dim emp3 As Boolean

With Sheet1

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("z1AI:z1AT")) = 0 And wVOE1 = False And IsEmpty(Sheet1.[z1DQ]) = True Then _
    emp1 = False _
Else _
    emp1 = True
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("z1FH:z1FS")) = 0 And wVOE2 = False And IsEmpty(Sheet1.[z1IV]) Then _
    emp2 = False _
Else _
    emp2 = True
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("z1KL:z1KW")) = 0 And wVOE3 = False And IsEmpty(Sheet1.[z1NZ]) Then _
    emp3 = False _
Else _
    emp3 = True

End With
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second code block your With Sheet1 block isn't being used by the enclosed code, as your `Range()` references have no leading period to link them to the `With` object

```
Dim emp1 As Boolean
Dim emp2 As Boolean
Dim emp3 As Boolean

With Sheet1

    Debug.Print .Name, .Parent.Name '<< check it's the right sheet
                                    '   and the right workbook...

    emp1 = Not (WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("AI:AT")) = 0 And _
                wVOE1 = False And IsEmpty(.[DQ]))

    emp2 = Not (WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("FH:FS")) = 0 And _
                wVOE2 = False And IsEmpty(.[IV]))

    emp3 = Not (WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("KL:KW")) = 0 And _
                wVOE3 = False And IsEmpty(.[NZ]))

End With
```

Comment: For some reason that CountA function still is not working for me; emp1 is only dependent on wVOE1 and [DQ].  My first reaction is to think that there is a different part of my code that is somehow interfering, but the fact that the individual reference is working makes me think otherwise. @TimWilliams

Comment: Hard to suggest anything without the rest of your code.  Is it for sure the right sheet in the right workbook? Is `Sheet1` here the "built-in" object or a variable you've declared and assigned?

Comment: And is the sheet with the `Name` of "Sheet1" the same one as the one with the `CodeName` of `Sheet1`?  Your `Sheet1` is referring to the one with that `CodeName` (or to a variable you have defined yourself) but that sheet might be showing in Excel itself as "Sheet3".

Comment: Oops - my previous comment was intended to be pinged to @khelm, but I left the ping out.  (Must be time I went and got my morning coffee!)

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with VBA, so it's very possible I'm referencing incorrectly.  Since the code is working with individual referencing, is it safe to assume that I'm referencing correctly?  Thanks for your help.  I'm sorry it seems I haven't provided full information.  I'll have to go back through previous code and see if it's buggy.  @TimWilliams

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K, I just got your comment.  I think my above comment to Tim may also speak to your question.  Thanks also for your help.  I think I'll have to do a bit more investigation to get to the root of the problem.